# Why variable is not decremented?

Tags: angularjs

In Angular JS controller there is variable:

```
$scope.currentCount = {
   'subscribers' : 0
}
```

Also in HTML template:

```
<span>{{currentCount.subscribers}}</span>
```

When I call method in this controller, this variable is not decremented in template, why?

```
$scope.saveSubscriber = function (type, name) {
    $scope.saveSubObj.type = type;
    $http({
      url: "/subscribe",
      method: "POST",
      data: $.param($scope.saveSubObj),
      headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}

       }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {

           $scope.currentCount.subscribers--;

       }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                        //TODO
       });
}
```

Look at success AJAX response:

```
$scope.currentCount.subscribers--;
```

Comment: Have you confirmed that the success function is being called?

Comment: What does `$scope` reference if you log it?

Comment: @Sahe Just to test, please add  `$scope.$apply();` after `$scope.currentCount.subscribers--;` and see if the value gets updated?

Comment: If do `console.log($scope.currentCount.subscribers--);` in success it gives me value 1

Comment: If simply do `$scope.$apply();` after then:  `Error: [$rootScope:inprog]`

Comment: @mohamedrias why you need to apply digest cycle as it not needed, because $http runs digest cycle after resolving promise..

Comment: @Sahe try use `--$scope.currentCount.subscribers;` pre operator instead of post decreament

Comment: @pankajparkar yes true. Just wanted to see whether is it because of that.

Comment: Tried, does not work

Comment: Now shows on page by default `{{currentCount.subscribers}} // == 1`

Comment: I found reason in part of code: `<span ng-show="isMessages(<?=$notificationsCount['subscriber']?>, 3)">{{currentCount.subscribers}}</span>`   Ajs: `$scope.isMessages = function (num, type) {$scope.currentCount.messages = num;} `If delete `ng-show=""` from template all works, but donot understand why?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it fired the success method? I just checked and got the correct result in my local testing.

Could you please put `$scope.currentCount.subscribers--;` inside the `$http` `error()` method as well? Let's check then whether it decreases or not.

Comment: Tried, is same case. I hope AJAX is returns true. I added `alert('dd');` in `success` it works

Comment: Are you using ng-click for invoking the method saveSubscriber() ? Your code looks absolute correct.

Comment: I use `ng-change="saveSubscriber()";`

Comment: `$scope.saveSubscriber = function (type, name) {}`

Comment: I meant, did {{currentCount.subscribers}} show its initial value in the template before triggering ng-change?